# mvn site in multimodule project causes jxr to fail

Tags: maven, maven-3

When running mvn site, the jxr plugin fails with this, any clues ?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at sun.nio.cs.ISO_8859_1$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop(ISO_8859_1.java:9
        at sun.nio.cs.ISO_8859_1$Decoder.decodeLoop(ISO_8859_1.java:119)
        at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:561)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:317)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:126)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:112)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
        at java.io.StreamTokenizer.read(StreamTokenizer.java:500)
        at java.io.StreamTokenizer.nextToken(StreamTokenizer.java:563)
        at java.io.StreamTokenizer.nextToken(StreamTokenizer.java:731)
        at java.io.StreamTokenizer.nextToken(StreamTokenizer.java:731)
        at java.io.StreamTokenizer.nextToken(StreamTokenizer.java:731)

Comment: Looks your memory is to low...How did you call mvn site? Which Maven version? Which plugin version? How does you pom file look like?

Comment: mvn site maven 3.2.1, jxr 2.4